# Is there a better particular solution ansatz to this ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, bessel-functions

I am trying to find the **particular** solution, $y(x)$, for (spherical Bessel ) ODE, where 
$$y''+\frac{2}{x} y' +\frac{A^2 x^2 - B}{x^2}y =  C   $$
Here $A,B,C\in \mathbb {R} _{>0}$.

I know what the homogeneous solution is and I tried the usual polynomial ansatz for the particular solution $y(x) = \sum a_n x^n$ but I get an infinite series.

Could there possibly be a better ansatz? Anyhow, thought I should check. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to find a particular solution and thus analytically solve the ODE. But this involves complicated integrals where Bessel functions are involves (see below).

This seems not simpler that solving with infinite series.

[image]